# checking for a grace period of 30days in dates yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to do a validation before save and check if the dates exist +/- 30days. 
It keeps showing me my own error "within grace period". My reasoning is if I subtract/add 30days to user's input and search for it. If it exists, then it's still within grace period. 
What am i missing?

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    //subtract number of days to see if a record exist
    $minusthirtyDays = date( 'Y-m-d',strtotime($this->effective_from_date ." -30 days")); 
    $addthirtyDays = date( 'Y-m-d',strtotime($this->effective_to_date ." +30 days"));

    $criteria->compare('pid',$this->id1,'OR');
    $criteria->compare('pid',$this->id2);

    $criteria->addBetweenCondition('effective_from_date', $minusthirtyDays,$this->effective_to_date,'OR');
    $criteria->addBetweenCondition('effective_to_date',$this->effective_to_date ,$addthirtyDays,'OR');

    $model = self::model()->findall($criteria);
    if (!empty($model)) {
        $this->addError($attribute, "Date is within grace period of 30 days.");
    }
```

Comment: Does it work without $criteria->compare('pid',$this->id1,'OR'); $criteria->compare('pid',$this->id2); ?

Comment: it does submit, but it isn't checking the dates properly. I have a date ending 4/30, and i input 5/15, it went through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$minusthirtyDays = date( 'Y-m-d',strtotime($this->effective_from_date ." -30 days")); 
$addthirtyDays = date( 'Y-m-d',strtotime($this->effective_to_date ." +30 days"));
```

There must be

```
$minusthirtyDays = date( 'Y-m-d',strtotime("-30 days", strtotime($this->effective_to_date)); 
$addthirtyDays = date( 'Y-m-d',strtotime("+30 days", strtotime($this->effective_to_date)));
```

See [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php) function